# Http live streaming - Gopro

Tags: ios, ios5, http-live-streaming, m3u8, gopro

How we can capture live stream from gopro device in ios app and send it through opentok ?

I can stream from http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8 in browser.

Now I want it to send to the server for live streaming on other devices.

Comment: Are you asking for some library / tutorial or do you have some semi working code we should fix some bugs in!? Keep in mind that the first option is off-topic and does not belong on SO.

Comment: I have a live stream URL "http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8"

I am able to play video from this URL in my iOS App. Now I want to send data which comes from this URL to another device.

Is there any way to get data in chunks from the Live Stream URL?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS video player uses standard HTTP GET requests to download the stream. You need to write a small program to download the HTTP entities and upload them to a public server (or opentok if that's what you're after).

The data is **ALREADY** in chunks when coming from the live stream. The m3u8 file is a text playlist that lists the chunks! You can take a look with a traffic analysis tool like Wireshark, Fiddler or Charles.

Comment: I am not even able to get the streaming link. The live directory is coming up empty.

Can you help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941979/gopro-3-streaming-links-missing-in-live-directory)?

Comment: @ArjunChiddarwar I don't know anything about debugging cameras, sorry.