# GoPro 3 streaming links missing in live directory

Tags: streaming, vlc, live, live-streaming, gopro

So by following different instructions online, I connected laptop to GoPro 3 silver using wifi.

I browsed to the URL 
http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/

and this is where I am supposed to see options where I could copy the URL for media streaming.

But this image shows that live folder is coming up empty.
I am expecting to find something like :  http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8

Note- The GoPro is in "GOPRO APP" mode

Thoughts?

[image: Empty Live folder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there is some issue with gopro.

Once I connected the GoPro3 with its android app and started streaming on app. the streaming on http would start. weird but that's how it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first call the preview on URL: 
 http://10.5.5.9/camera/PV?t=PASSWORD&p=%02
Password is the SSID pass